# using socket to create a server and then using urllib to get the data, getting an error "No connection could be made because the target machine"

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, server, urllib

I used this code to create the server

```
import socket

HOST = "10.34.9.130"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 8080  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        data= "this mf got connected".encode()
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        conn.sendall(data)
        print(data)
```

then i used this code to access the data

```
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://localhost:8080").read()
print(data.decode())
```

I dont understand why i am getting this error

`raise URLError(err)`

`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>`

I just trying to create a server with socket and then acces it with urllib client.

Comment: The standard loopback address is `127.0.0.1`, not `10.34.9.130`. That's just a local IP address in your LAN.

Answer (score 1):

(Windows does have some IP quirks, but this should work)

Edit your code so you use "127.0.0.1", absent other problems it should work.

(And you really should remove that comment, its textbook wrong).

```
test@M1ly-mba4 ~ % dig localhost

(edited)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localhost.      0   IN  A   127.0.0.1
(edited)
```

Comment: yes, I understand the problem and also apology for the comment.

Comment: Thx... hopefully your question in SO will help others in the future!